# In a page, how to refresh a component from another?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

I have two different components in a page, one allows to add an item to a database via API, the other fetches the list of items in this database. How can I call a { refresh } of the list ListComponent once a new item is added from AddItemComponent? Maybe using some VueUse function?

`pages/index.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <Foo />
  <Bar />
</template>
```

Below is the component from where I add new items.

`components/foo.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <h1>ADD NEW ITEM</h1>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="name"
    label="Name"
    type="text"
    @click:append="add"
  ></v-text-field>
</template>

<script setup>
const name = ref();

async function add() {
  const res = await useFetch(
    "http://api.test/add",
    {
      method: "POST",
      query: {
        name,
      },
    }
  );
}
</script>
```

Below is the component showing the list of items and which I need to refresh when a new item is add.

`components/bar.vue`

```html
<template>
  <h1>LIST</h1>
  <v-data-table
    v-if="mydata"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="mydata.data"
  >
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script setup>
const { data: mydata } = await useFetch(
  "http://api.test/list",
  {
    transform(data) {
      return JSON.parse(data);
    },
    pick: ["data"],
  }
);

const headers = reactive([
  { title: "ID", key: "id" },
  { title: "Nom", key: "name" },
  { title: "Création", key: "created_at" }
]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have read about event bus from here [Event Bus In vuejs](https://medium.com/@certosinolab/using-event-bus-in-vue-js-3-425aae8c21a6) .So from my understanding you should use this.here how you should do it.
In foo component use

```
import { eventBus } from '@/event-bus';
```

and in you add method

```
async function add() {
const res = await useFetch(
"http://api.test/add",
{
  method: "POST",
  query: {
    name,
  },
 }
 );
  eventBus.$emit('newItemAdded');
 }
```

After this in bar component use mounted lifecycle hook

```
 mounted(){
 eventBus.$on('newItemAdded', () => {
  //update the list when event is triggered 
  this.refreshList();
});
}
```